# Using classes in a module from the lib directory - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a setup in the lib directory like so:

```
lib/
  copy_process.rb
  copy_process/
    processor.rb
```

The copy_process.rb and processor.rb contain the module definition CopyProcess. The copy_process.rb defines the CopyFile class as well:

```
module CopyProcess
  class CopyFile
  end
end
```

The processor.rb is structured like so:

```
module CopyProcess
  class Processer

  end
end
```

In one of its methods, it creates a new copy file object:

```
def append_file_if_valid(file_contents, headers, files, file_name)
  unless headers
    raise "Headers not found"
  else
    files << CopyProcess::CopyFile.new()
  end
end
```

When I used these files as part of a command line ruby program, it worked fine. However, i started putting it into a rails app, and I have written cucumber/capybara tests to hit the buttons and so forth where this is used. I initialize a Processor object from one of my AR models, and call the above method a few times. It cannot seem to find the CopyFile class, even though I have the following code in my application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Any ideas?

===============================================================

**Edit** Above was solved by extracting the copy file class into it's own file under lib.
I now have another issue:

The CopyFile class refers to module-level helper methods that sit in lib/copy_process.rb, like so:

```
module CopyProcess
  # Gets the index of a value inside an array of the given array
  def get_inner_index(value, arr)
    idx = nil
    arr.each_with_index do |e, i|
      if e[0] == value
        idx = i
      end
    end
    return idx
  end

  def includes_inner?(value, arr)
    bool = false
    arr.each { |e| bool = true if e[0] == value  }
    return bool
  end


  # Encloses the string in double quotes, in case it contains a comma
  # @param [String] - the string to enclose
  # @return [String]
  def enclose(string)
    string = string.gsub(/\u2019/, '&rsquo;')
    if string.index(',')
      return "\"#{string}\""
    else
      return string
    end
  end
end
```

When I run my cucumber tests, i get the following error:

```
 undefined method `includes_inner?' for CopyProcess:Module (NoMethodError)
  ./lib/copy_process/copy_file.rb:64:in `set_element_name_and_counter'
```

Which refers to this method here:

```
def set_element_name_and_counter(element_names, name)
  if !CopyProcess::includes_inner?(name, element_names)
    element_names << [name, 1]
  else
    # if it's in the array already, find it and increment the counter
    current_element = element_names[CopyProcess::get_inner_index(name, element_names)]
    element_names[CopyProcess::get_inner_index(name, element_names)] = [current_element[0], current_element[1]+1]
  end
  element_names
end
```

I also tried moving the copy_file.rb and other files in the lib/copy_process/ directory up a level into the lib directory. I then received the following error:

```
 Expected /Users/aaronmcleod/Documents/work/copy_process/lib/copy_file.rb to define CopyFile (LoadError)
  ./lib/processor.rb:48:in `append_file_if_valid'
```

The line that the error states creates an instance of CopyFile. I guess rails doesn't like loading the files in that fashion, and for the former setup, I think the copy_file.rb is having issues loading the rest of the module. I tried requiring it and so forth, but no luck. You can also find my most recent code here: https://github.com/agmcleod/Copy-Process/tree/rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` should be sufficient. This tells rails to start looking for properly structured files at /lib.

Second, I think that you're running into issues because `CopyFile` isn't where rails expects it to be. As far as I know your setup 'should' work but have you tried seperating `CopyFile` out into its own file under the copy_process folder? My guess is that since the copy_process folder exists, it is expecting all `CopyProcess::*` classes to be defined there instead of the copy_process.rb.

**EDIT**: You may consider opening another question, but the second half of your question is a different problem entirely.

You define methods in your module like so,

```
module X
  def method_one
    puts "hi"
  end
end
```

Methods of this form are *instance* methods on the module, and they have very special restrictions. For instance, you can not access them from outside the module definition (I'm skeptical how these worked previously). Executing the above gives

```
> X::method_one
NoMethodError: undefined method `method_one' for X:Module
```

If you want to access these methods from other scopes you have a few options.

Use **Class Methods**

```
 module X
   def self.method_one
     puts "hi"
   end
 end
 X::hi #=> "hi"
```

Use **Mixins**

```
module X
  module Helpers
    def method_one
      puts "hi"
    end
  end
end

class CopyFile
  include X::Helpers

  def some_method
    method_one #=> "hi"
    self.method_one #=> "hi"
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes after moving that, it seemed to do the trick. I know i tried that before, but maybe i missed a step, or something else i changed fixed it. However, to further complicate the matter, i have some lone helper methods part of the module in the copy_processor.rb file, that the CopyFile class references. Those are giving me NoMethodError exceptions. Any suggestions there?

Comment: Again just guessing, but it sounds like copy_process.rb isn't being loaded. I'm not 100% sure why not, but as a test you could try including the methods in your `CopyFile` class, perhaps under `private`.

Comment: The methods would be called like so: CopyProcess::my_method()

Comment: This is a bit of a hack, but you can try tossing a `require 'copy_process'` in the CopyFile definition. If that fixes the problem, you could try and debug why rails' autoloading isn't working for the module definition.

Comment: Yeah no luck from that. I tried moving the files up one level, so everything was in the lib directory. Now it complains that copy_file.rb was expected to define CopyFile

Comment: Could you update your question with the method signature, function call and error?

Comment: That would do it. Went for the mixin route. I kept the copyfile in the module as well :)